# How can I show that $K(i)E(i)-K(i)^2=\pi/4$?

Tags: arc-length, elliptic-integrals

[The equality](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=K%28-1%29E%28-1%29-K%28-1%29%5E2)
$$K(i)E(i)-K(i)^2=\pi/4\tag 1$$ follows from
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}}d\theta=\frac{K(k)-E(k)}{k^2}$$
and evaluation of the integral when $k^2=-1$ by converting the integral into a beta function integral.

Can we show the equality $(1)$ in some other ways? Is there a geometric meaning of this identity?

Thanks in advance.

Note: WA is using $m=k^2$ convention.

Comment: Use the formula $K(ik) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+k^2}}K(k/\sqrt{1+k^2})$ and $E(ik) = \sqrt{1+k^2}E(k/\sqrt{1+k^2})$ along with Legendre identity $KE'+K'E-KK'=\pi/2$.